# Oracle Apex - Can I edit layout of Individual Pages?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How can i edit layout of individual pages in Oracle Apex. I tried changing templates and properties in shared components but it applies to all the pages.
On one page, I need different layout of buttons and items and on the other page, a different.

Answer (score 0):

You can create more than one page template, for different types of page.  And you can also make page-specific styling changes using in-line CSS in the page attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It applies to all pages, because all of your pages refer one template. And when you change this template, all pages changes. Create a copy of template, and then refer your individual page to this new template.